# Axios: conditionally chaining requests?

Tags: javascript, axios, rate-limiting

I need to make an API request to some endpoint, but would like to check beforehand whether I still have remaining calls to the API by checking another endpoint. If I don't have any calls remaining, I would rather not make the main request.

My current code:

```js
const axios = require('axios')

axios
  .get('http://endpoint.api/limit')
  .then(res => res.data)
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
  .then(data => {
    if (data.remaining > 0) {
      axios
        .get('http://endpoint.api/main')
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
        .then(data => console.log(data))
    }
  )
```

Comment: So what's the problem? One thing that stands out is your first `catch` will turn the rejected promise into a resolved one. Probably not a problem right now but it could be later

Comment: If you want to chain you logic based on results from promises, you can return them as: if (data.remaining > 0) { return axios./*following request pf getting the main endpoint */ } return data;

Comment: @Phil I just wasn't sure if this was the right way of doing what I intended. And yes you're right, the second request is made no matter what. I should both check for the rate limit and make the second call when the first request is valid, i.e., inside the first `then`. And yes @azamat-zorkanov, I guess I should always return somthing. Thanks!

Comment: Just move your `catch` calls **after** the `then` calls **AND / OR** return `Promise.reject(error)` or `throw error` in your `catch` callbacks